# Is Android unit testing on a physical device actually a thing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

Firebase has physical devices for testing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/available-testing-devices however it's a little expensive.

I was wondering if testing things on a physical Android device is a real thing and if there are frameworks for that. I know that there are unit tests that are mocked and run on the computer, but some things like the Android Media Codec Decoder can only be tested on the device

Answer (score 0):

Generally you write as much as you can as junit tests because running things on a real device is MUCH slower-  both because the hardware is less powerful and due to the slowness of installing and launching an app on the USB connected device.

That said, android does have instrumentation tests, which are unit tests that run on an Android device.  Generally you run them on emulators because its easier to set everything up, and to run it on a remote server.  But you can run them on a physical device, you'd just need to have it attached to the machine running the test.  You just generally don't do it, unless you're testing a specific bug on a specific device.

For your specific case-  why can't you test the codec on an emulator?  The emulator should have it-  its literally an Android OS running on a virtual machine.  The only thing you can't really test on it is hardware, which isn't applicable here.

Comment: but is there a framework for doing such things? Like clicking stuff on the screen, and getting the results back form the emulator?

Comment: Yes.  Look up Espresso and Android instrumentation tests.